# Cygwin - egrep command to find patterns from a given text file

Tags: grep, cygwin

I've been asked to find the set of words that begin with a substring of length 3
containing the characters a, b and c and which additionally
contains another disjoint substring containing the same 3
characters

ex. 
abcacb
acbbac

help me finding a regex for this.
Thankyou

edit:
abcbac - a,b,c should be there as the first 3 letters, then a,b,c should change their order from previous 3 letters. just 6 character strings.

acbbca
abccba
bacbca
etc....

Comment: Just noticing there are a lot of these sorts of questions now...

Comment: @Kusalananda also, similar question with `o,n,i` was asked in SO and then deleted

Comment: I'd say GNU `grep -Pwo '(abc|acb|bac|bca|cab|cba)\w*(?1)\w*'`

Comment: so `abcabc` shouldn't match?

Answer (score 2):

(Solutions here  assuming GNU `grep` when built with PCRE support (as is typically the case on cygwin)).

The first half of your requirements would mean.

```
grep -Pwo '(abc|acb|bac|bca|cab|cba)\w*(?1)\w*'
```

Or possibly:

```
grep -Pwo '(abc|acb|bac|bca|cab|cba)\w*\1\w*'
```

For the second half that seems to contradict the first half:

```
grep -Pwo '(abc|acb|bac|bca|cab|cba)(?!\1)(?1)'
```

Would find the *words* (*word* being defined as a sequence of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` characters in this case) that start with a sequence of 3 characters made up of `a`, `b` and `c` (one of each) followed but another one of such sequences (`(?1)` referring to the same regexp as in the first `(...)` group) provided it's not the same as the first one (`\1` refers to the string that was matched by the first `(...)` capture group and `(?!...)` is a *negative look ahead* operator).

```
$ echo abcbca abcbcax abcabc aaabbb xcabacb abcacb-blah |
    grep -Pwo '(abc|acb|bac|bca|cab|cba)(?!\1)(?1)'
abcbca
abcacb
```

Comment: excellent use of PCRE... `grep -owE '(abc|acb|bac|bca|cab|cba){2}' | grep -v '\(...\)\1'` as workaround ?

Comment: in Cygwin I have to take this out from a given text file.. it indiactes a matcher error

Answer (score 0):

This should do it :

```
grep -Ew '[a-c]{3}.*[a-c]{3}'
```

- `-E` to match regexes
- `-w` to match only words
- `[a-c]{3}` will match exactly 3 characters from the `a-c` set
- `.*` will match anything between

Comment: it is not clear in OP's questions, but I think OP meant `abc` in any order but necessarily containing all three letters... also not clear if OP expects some characters in between the two sets of `abc` in any order

Comment: my regex handles all the not clear points. `[a-c]{3}` will match `bca` or any combination of `abc`, and `.*` will match none or any character between the two `[a-c]` sets

Comment: `[a-c]{3}` will match `aaa` as well...

Comment: @Sundeep meant that your regexp matches `aaa whatever bbb` for instance. It doesn't look like that's what the OP expected. It also doesn't match on `abcxxxbcayyy`

Comment: oooops. right, i missed that. In that case the good solution is offered by @Stéphane.